# Connect TIBCO EMS with bash

Tags: bash, shell, tibco-ems

I try to write a bash script that can read and write to tibco ems server. Is it possible? What i need to do that ?

thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to develop a utility able to write messages to a queue and read messages from a queue. This can be done using EMS Java API. Then this utility would be called from your script.

A good starting point would be to look at the samples provided with the product in the <TIBCO_HOME>/ems/8.6/samples/java directory (look at tibjmsMsgConsumer.java and tibjmsMsgProducer.java).